# Accessing Facebook UID C# SDK

Tags: c#, .net, facebook, .net-2.0, facebook-c#-sdk

After a user has logged in using Facebook I need to access their Facebook UID.

I have attempted to use the code found here: http://blog.prabir.me/post/Facebook-CSharp-SDK-Writing-your-first-Facebook-Application.aspx

I have using statements for Facebook and Facebook.Web but am unable to use FacebookOAuthResult or FacebookOAuthClient. "facebook" and "Facebook" show up in intellisense but I can't find these classes anywhere within them

I am using the DLLs from the .net 3.5 folder of the Facebook C# SDK but my project has to target .net 2.0.

I would appreciate either a fix for this problem or an alternative solution for accessing the UID of the currently logged in facebook user via C# .net 2.0.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internally Facebook C# SDK makes use of certain linq methods.

As stated in the requirement Facebook C# SDK requires minimum of .net 3.5 SP1.

We don't have plans to support any .net version below 3.5 SP1.